# Can we add ephemeral-storage in LimitRange?

Tags: kubernetes

in LimitRange in k8s we can simply limit the ram and the cpu and can we do that for ephemeral-storage as wella?

Answer (score 3):

To set default requests and limits on ephemeral storage for each container in  `mytest` namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: storage-limit
  namespace: mytest
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      ephemeral-storage: 2Gi
    defaultRequest:
      ephemeral-storage: 1Gi 
    type: Container
```

To change scope to Pod simply change to `type: Pod`

Comment: defaults can't be set if type: Pod is set. Everything is right about your answer except the last line. only max/min is possible for type: Pod